# Is it possible to configure proxy setting in apache-tomcat-7.0.54 on ubuntu?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, proxy

I have manually downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.54.tar.gz and unpack it in **/usr/local/**. I have searched for proxy configuration on many websites but they are talking about **httpd.conf** or **apache2.conf** and **./configure** file. I searched many times for these files in **/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.54** but i find nothing.

Please tell me, proxy configuration is possible with **apache-tomcat-7.0.54** or not. If it is not possible than tell me how is it possible?

Should i use **apache** and **tomcat** both for proxy setting?

please suggest me any way to do proxy configuration for tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You you use the startup or catalina scripts you can certainly use the environment to do that, try setting a JAVA_OPTS variable to something like

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy> 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy> 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> 
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=<domain_one>|<domain two> $JAVA_OPTS
```

Best regards, Dido